# Fast polynomial division algorithm over finite field

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, finite-fields

Recently, I am working on polynomial division. Suppose coefficients of all polynomials are elements in $GF(2^q)$. I want to calculate the remainder such that

$f(x) = g(x)q(x) + r(x)$ (1)

I searched a lot, and one algorithm draws my attention is the one in the following link

http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST12/scribe/lect06.pdf

The key idea is as below:

Let the $Rev$ denotes reciprocal of a polynomial (reverse order of the coefficient). Then one can obtain

$Rev(q) = Rev(g)^{-1}Rev(f)~~$mod$~~x^{deg(f) - deg(g)}$ (2)

where $Rev(g)^{-1}$ is defined as

$Rev(g)^{-1}Rev(g) = 1$ mod $x^{deg(g)+1}$

Then $r(x)$ can be obtained by substitute $q(x)$ back to the equation (1). If one follows this algorithm, he or she needs to multiply twice. Once at equation (2) and once at equation (1).

However, since I am only interested in $r(x)$. Also, my application scenario is that I have a lot of $f(x)$ needs to be divided by the same $g(x)$. Therefore,  is there anyway I can "substitute" (2) into (1) to get only one equation such that only one multiplication is needed (other multiplications can be precalculated since $g(x)$ is the same). I tried to do that, yet I failed. It is mostly because there is non-linear operation "mod" in (2) so that linearity does not hold anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Is it not possible to do Fourier Transforms on Finite Fields?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to exist something called a [Number Theoretic Transform (NTT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_%28general%29) which should have the properties of a Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), one of which is that it turns convolution into multiplication. As (I assume) polynomial multiplication for finite fields also are convolution of their coefficients if "fast" / factored versions of the NTT exist these should provide speed-ups at least for multiplying / dividing high-order polynomials.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the NTT you mentioned is an interesting topic. It might be helpful to things I am doing right now. I will start look into it. Thanks